# write custom handler class which should not overwrite token feature

Tags: javascript, json, api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

How to write custom handler class which can access json request payload, also not overwrite the token feature available in APIAuthenticationHandler. I have tried to write class and always get error as below,

```
[2016-12-07 15:56:45,643] ERROR - APIFactory Error initializing API handler: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.RequestAuthenticationHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.RequestAuthenticationHandler cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v3
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:455)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-12-07 15:56:45,676]  INFO - DataBridge user admin connected
[2016-12-07 15:56:45,956]  WARN - SynapseXMLConfigurationFactory API configuration cannot be built - Continue in fail-safe mode
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error initializing API handler: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.RequestAuthenticationHandler
        at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.rest.APIFactory.handleException(APIFactory.java:202)
```

I have also tried to extend AbstractHandler and implement ManagedLifecycle by copying all code from APIAuthenticationHandler, but it has compilation error because of dependency. how to solve APISecurityConstants, Authenticator and Utils.isCORSEnabled() dependency.

Is it possible to restrict resource request by get parameter in API manager ?
If yes, please provide link.

I am using WSO2 Api Manager 2.0.

Comment: 1) where did you put your custom jar? 2) explain your last question further.

Comment: I have placed custom jar at /repository/components/lib directory. suppose I have request as endpoint?name=xyz. Then based on the parameter value that is xyz should not able to access the resource.

Comment: The core imports you need are org.apache.synapse.MessageContext, org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext, org.apache.synapse.rest.AbstractHandler. It's not surprising that the engine can't find your class if it doesn't compile!

Comment: Start by just extending org.apache.synapse.rest.AbstractHandler. You don't need WSO2's handleFault method, just log your errors and `return false` until you get it working.